# Java Boolean.valueOf() equivalent in Kotlin?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, boolean

Is there a Kotlin equivalent of `Boolean.valueOf()` of java? The closest I found was `.toBoolean()`.
But if the string is null `.toBoolean()` would create a NPE.

Did anyone come across this? Am I missing something understanding?

Comment: To prevent the NPE: `someString?.toBoolean()`. This is only needed if `someString` is nullable.

Comment: "if the string is null .toBoolean() would create an NPE" Is that not what you want?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It is, as already mentioned, `.toBoolean()`.

It works pretty simple: if the value of a String is `true`, ignoring case, the returning value is `true`. In any other case, it's false. Which means, if the string isn't a boolean, it will return false.

Kotlin essentially has two variations of types: `Any` and `Any?`. `Any` can of course be absolutely any class, or referring to the actual class `Any`.

`toBoolean` requires a `String`, which means a non-null String. It's pretty basic:

```
val someString = "true"
val parsedBool = someString.toBoolean()
```

It gets slightly more complicated if you have nullable types. As I mentioned, `toBoolean` requires a `String`. A `String?` != `String` in these cases.

So, if you have a nullable type, you can use the safe call and elvis operator

```
val someString: String? = TODO()
val parsedBool = someString?.toBoolean() ?: false
```

Or, if you can live with a nullable boolean, you don't need the elvis operator. But if the String is null, so will the boolean be.

Just an explanation of the above:

```
someString?.//If something != null
    toBoolean() // Call toBoolean
    ?: false // Else, use false
```

Also, you can't compile a program that uses `toBoolean` on a nullable reference. The compiler blocks it.

---

And finally, for reference, the method declaration:

```
/**
 * Returns `true` if the contents of this string is equal to the word "true", ignoring case, and `false` otherwise.
 */
@kotlin.internal.InlineOnly
public actual inline fun String.toBoolean(): Boolean = java.lang.Boolean.parseBoolean(this)
```

Answer (score 7):

String.toBoolean

Returns true if the contents of this string is equal to the word "true", ignoring case, and false otherwise.

In Kotlin, a String is never null, so you don't have to check it.  This returns a Boolean (true only if string value is 'true')

```
myString.toBoolean()
```

Now if you have a String? type and want a Boolean

```
myString?.toBoolean() ?: false
```

If you are ok with a Boolean? type returned

```
myString?.toBoolean()
```

Answer (score 2):

You should know if it is `null` before the call, because you are either dealing with a `String` or a `String?`. `?` is the suffix that Kotlin uses to designate nullable types.

If you have a `String`, then you should be able to use `toBoolean()`.

If you have a `String?` — and so you may have a value or you may have `null` — you could use a null-safe call plus the Elvis operator to specify what value you want if the `String?` is `null`:

```
val foo: String? = "true"
val bar: String? = null

println(foo?.toBoolean())
println(bar?.toBoolean() ?: false)
```

This prints:

```
true
false
```

`bar?.toBoolean()` evaluates to `null`, and `null ?: false` evaluates to `false`.